# Can the commit status message be customized in Travis CI?

Tags: travis-ci

Our project runs multiple checks in Travis CI. When a build fails, it would be great to have an indication on github of what went wrong. If we could have it say "compile failed", or "tests failed", or "style conflicts" or whatever it would be easier than having to scan the build log for details.

As it is, the only status github is given is "The Travis CI build failed". Does travis have any facility to customize this message as things fail in my build?

Answer (score 3):

The message used for Travis CI commit status messages can't be customized at the moment.